# Largest eigenvalue, semidefinite programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The problem is to minimize the largest eigenvalue of a function of $x$.

objective:
$$ \min\{\lambda_{\max}(A(x))\}$$
where
$$A(x) = A_0+x_1A_1+x_2A_2+...x_nA_n$$ and all $A$ is positive semidefinite.

This problem can be solved by equivalent  SDP:
$$\text{minimize} \ \ t \\ \text{subject to} \ \ \ A(x)\leq tI$$
since
$$\lambda_{\max}(A(x)) \leq t \ \ \\ \text{iff} \ \ \ A(x)-tI \leq0$$
My question is why is that?

I can't find special property of eigenvalue for  positive semidefinite matrix where the above inequality holds

Can someone give me a brief proof? or point out where I can find the proof.

Comment: Do you mean $A(x) = \sum_{n} x^n A_n$ ?

Comment: no x is a vector $x_n$ is element of the vector, all the A are PSD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand most of your question, but the reason that $\lambda_\max(A(x))\le t$ is equivalent to $A(x)-tI\le 0$ is clear, because $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A(x)$ if and only if $\lambda-t$ is an eigenvalue of $A(x)-tI$. (More specifically, this is because $Ax=\lambda x$ iff $(A(x)-tI)v=(\lambda -t)v$, where $v$ denotes an eigenvector.) Therefore, $\lambda_\max(A(x))\le t$ if and only if all eigenvalues of $A(x)-tI$ are nonpositive, i.e. if and only if $A(x)-tI\le0$.

Comment: thank you !. I got it.
I think I need to go back and review my linear algebra.
BTW, I think my statement is not clear. This problem is famous in SDP:
http://orion.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/w04workshop.d/wphotos.d/henrycourse.pdf

Comment: This belongs as a comment and user1551 has given an excellent answer. I would like to add another perspective. For a given positive definite matrix $A=UDU^T$, think about the largest number $t$ such that all diagonal entries of $D-tI$ is less than or equal to zero. In addition, observe that $A-tI \leq 0$ is equivalent to $D-tI \leq 0$ for all $t$.